Specific distance between sets of points
Let us have closed curve without self-intersections,
initial point $O$ and curve parameter $t$, $0 \leq t \leq t_{\max}$ so $t(O) = 0 = t_{\max}$.
There are two sets of points on the curve, which are given by parameter values
for each point:
$$\mathcal{P}_1 = \{ t^1_1, t^1_2, \ldots \}, \mathcal{P}_2 = \{ t^2_1, t^2_2, \ldots \}$$
Firstly we should introduce circular distance between points as shortest parameter distance:
$$\mathscr{d}(p(t_1), p(t_2)) = \min ( (t_1-t_2)\bmod t_{\max}, (t_2-t_1)\bmod t_{\max} )$$
The first question: is such distance is formalised in mathematics?
Let's call circular distance between sets as
minimum of pairwise circular distances between points
$$\mathscr{D}(\mathcal{P}_1, \mathcal{P}_2) = \underset {\forall i,j}{\min}\mathscr{d}(p^1_i,p^2_j)$$
Also, I wonder if such definition is known?
Consider the simplest example.
On the unit circle there are two sets of points as vertices of regular $n$- and $m$- polygons.
The corresponding parameter is the polar angle $0 \leq \phi \leq 2 \pi$
One of the polygons is fixed, its first point has parameter  $\phi = 0$
Second polygon turned as a whole on angle $-\pi \leq \alpha \leq \pi$
We need to find $\alpha$  that maximizes
circular distance between sets of points $\mathscr{D}(\mathcal{P}_1, \mathcal{P}_2(\alpha))$.
If $n=m$, the solution is obvious: the points must alternate.
So  $\alpha=\pi/n$
I would like to find the best approximation to such alternation at $n \neq m$
It is not difficult to find an algorithmic solution to the problem.
Here are examples of several configurations found with interactive engine:
  
It seems to me, in the case of the right polygons,
we can find a closed formula (possibly using conditions),
but I can’t

For right $n$ and $m$ -gons maximal circular distance is:
$$
\mathscr{D}_{max}(\mathcal{P}_n, \mathcal{P}_m) = \pi \dfrac{\gcd(n,m)}{n m}
$$
